Electromagnetics - Finding voltages by iteration approach of solving Laplace equation with relaxation algorithm






The above pictures are from the book,Engineering electromagnetics by Hayt and Buck, 8e.
The problems in the pictures ask for calculation of nodal voltages at the intersecting lines of the grids at a,b,c or x,y inside closed shapes which are called troughs. It seems that this type of problem is solved by a relaxation algorithm in which each nodal voltage is calculated by taking the average of four adjacent nodes as in the grid.This calculation is done row by row until all rows are completed and the process is repeated until the nodal voltages remain nearly same with successive calculations of nodal voltages by the above approach. The grid is inside a trough. A trough maybe of any shape and may contain one or more smaller troughs of arbitrary shape. The grid has different boundary conditions such as a side with one voltage like 0V or otherwise. Sometimes two different outward lines of the grid meet at a gap which means that nodal voltage at that gap is half of the potential of those lines. Each solid line outside the grid or inside the grid at boundary of the trough is an equipotential surface. The size of the grid can vary and it can be something as 4x4 or 16x16 or 32x32 for increasing granularity of voltage for a square trough.
It is possible to find the voltages using a software tool like MATLAB/OCTAVE or C++/C. For this the entire grid inside a trough has to be constructed as a matrix and all boundary values have to entered in the matrix for the boundary conditions of the grid. It appears for each problem, the boundary conditions such as a voltage at each horizontal and vertical line of the grid outside the trough have to be entered and the size of the grid has to be programmed.
The question is: are there any Electromagnetic field or voltage solvers made with software which can automate the relaxation algorithm which can solve for nodal voltages inside the grid without entering each and every boundary condition at each horizontal and vertical line outside the grid?
References:
Engineering electromagnetics,8e, Hayt and Buck,pages 177 & 182, McGrawHill India.
Relaxation algorithm at Wikipedia: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relaxation_(iterative_method)

These are "rheographic" problems. You can use resistor foil and cut as needed. You can use an "equivalent" electronic foil and do the same with this.

QuickField springs to mind. I only use it for AC magnetics but, it'll do electrostatics.

Yes, all the boundary conditions have to be specified, somehow, but if they fit something that's easy to program, they don't have to be entered manually.

It seems specifying the boundary conditions for a single closed surface which is a known geometric shape is easy to program. However, if there are closed surfaces within closed surfaces with random shapes,  that may be slightly complex.

You can download the student version of QuickField for free but you can do very little with it. I have used it very rarely for over twenty years.

I have faced some electrostatics problems using MATHCAD 15 and developing programs after having studied the numerical methods for the solution of partial differential equations from the text " Numerical solutions of partial differential equations " by Mais and Markowitz. An example for a trough with square section is here in the photo although I took the cue from the old text "ELECTROMAGNETICS" 2nd edition by Kraus and Karver:


These are "rheographic" problems.
You can use resistor foil and cut as needed.
You can use an "equivalent" electronic foil and do the same with this.
Made with microcap v12

And when solved (part enlarged) ...

If it has a "symmetrical" part, the problem can be simplified.

It appears that the voltage drop is strictly not equal to the resistor drops. This appears as a rough estimate.

Logical. It depends of the number of resistors (or squares) ... It depends also of the "boundaries" and how there are done.

These are the results obtained from relaxation algorithm above.
It uses an equation \$V_x = \frac {V_{top} + V_{left} + V_{bottom} + V_{right}}{4} \$ for each and every node in each row after calculating boundary voltages of the shape on the grid. .
Values of voltages in the grid for triangle shape using the above algorithm are below. Number of iterations used were 100.
50          

0   100         

0   60.2542   100         

0   41.0167  74.259    100         

0   29.5534  56.0194   79.038    100         

0   21.1778  41.2271   60.1326   79.038    100         

0   13.9304   27.5788   41.2271   56.0194  74.259  100         

0   6.96522   13.9304   21.1778   29.5534  41.0167  60.2542  100         

0    0         0          0         0        0        0        0     100 


A C++ program used to calculate the above values for the triangle shape is below.
/*
Filename :Triangletrough.cpp
Author: AM
Version: 0.1
Description:
This program calculates voltages inside a triangle trough as a grid. 
The size of the grid can be chosen according to the accuracy of voltages required.
This program uses a 9x9 matrix to store values of traingle trough which occupies half of the matrix.
This is solution of problem 7-30 in Engineering electromagnetics by Hayt and Buck, 8e, MgrawHill. 
*/

#include<iostream>
#include <iomanip>
/* 
Function: void InitVoltages(double (*T)[9][9],double (&Tcopy)[9][9] )
arguments: Reference to array of the trough.
Description: 
Initializes the trough. 
*/
void InitVoltages(double (&T)[9][9] , double (&Tcopy)[9][9]);

/* 
Function: void CalculateVoltages(double (&T)[9][9]  , double (&Tcopy)[9][9])
arguments: References to array of the trough.
Description: 
Calculates voltages in the trough. 
*/
void CalculateVoltages(double (&T)[9][9]  , double (&Tcopy)[9][9]);

/* 
Function: PrintVoltages(double (&T)[9][9] );
arguments: Reference to array of the trough.
Description: 
Prints the trough. 
*/
void PrintVoltages(double (&T)[9][9] );

/* Function main */
int main(void)
{
    double T[9][9] = {0};
    double Tcopy[9][9] = {0};
    std::cout << "This program prints potentials inside a trough by solving laplace equation for a triangular trough " << std::endl; 
    InitVoltages(T, Tcopy);
    CalculateVoltages(T,Tcopy);
    PrintVoltages(T);
    return 0;
}

/* 
Function: void InitVoltages(double (*T)[9][9],double (&Tcopy)[9][9] )
arguments: Reference to array of the trough.
Description: 
Initializes the trough. 
*/
void InitVoltages(double (&T)[9][9] , double (&Tcopy)[9][9])
{
   int index =0;
   int Troughsize = 9;
   T[0][0] = T[8][8] = 50.0;
   for (index =1; index < Troughsize ; index ++)
   {
       Tcopy[index][0] =  T[index][0] = 0;
       Tcopy[8][index] = T[8][index] = 0;
       Tcopy[index][index] = T[index][index] = 100;
   }
}

/* 
Function: void PrintVoltages(double (&T)[9][9] )
arguments: pointer to array of the trough.
Description: 
Prints the trough. 
*/
void PrintVoltages(double (&T)[9][9] )
{
    size_t Troughsize =9;
    size_t i =0;
    size_t j =0;
    std::cout << "Voltages in the trough are: " << std::endl;
    for (i=0; i < Troughsize; i++)
    {
       for (j=0; j<=i; j++)
        {
           std::cout << std::left << std::setw(9) << T[i][j] << "   ";
        }
       std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    }
}


/* 
Function: void CalculateVoltages(double (&T)[9][9]  , double (&Tcopy)[9][9])
arguments: Reference to array of the trough.
Description: 
Calculates voltages in the trough. 
*/
void CalculateVoltages(double (&T)[9][9]  , double (&Tcopy)[9][9])
{
   size_t Troughsize = 9;
   size_t index =0;
   size_t j =0;
   size_t iterations = 100;
   for (size_t i =0; i <iterations; i++)
   {
       /*Use previous grid values to calculate current grid values */
       
       for (index =2 ;index < 8;index++)
       {
          for (j=1; j<= index-1; j++)
          {
               T[index][j] = (Tcopy[index-1][j] + Tcopy[index][j-1] + Tcopy[index+1][j] + Tcopy[index][j+1] ) /4;               
          }
       }  
       
       /* Keep previous Voltage values of grid in Tcopy */
       for (index = 0; index < Troughsize; index++)
       {  
          for (j=0; j<=index; j++)
          {
             Tcopy[index][j]= T[index][j];
          }
   
       }
   }   
}

Values of voltages in the grid for rectangular shape using the above algorithm are below. Number of iterations used were 100.
          
                100         100         100      100        


0       0       50         78.4369    92.3435    100        


0    18.0337    46.2429    71.4042    90.9369    100        


0    25.8918    45.5337    70         100        100        


20   40         40         40                               


A C++ program used to calculate the above values for the rectangle shape is below.
/*
Filename :rectangletrough.cpp
Author: AM
Version: 0.1
Description:
This program calculates voltages inside a rectangle trough as a grid. 
The size of the grid can be chosen according to the accuracy of voltages required.
This program uses a 2D matrix to store values.
This is solution of problem D7.6 in Engineering electromagnetics by Hayt and Buck, 8e, mcgrawHill. 
*/
#include<iostream>
#include <iomanip>
/* 
Function: void InitVoltages(double (&T)[5][6] , double (&Tcopy)[5][6])
arguments: Reference to array of the trough.
Description: 
Initializes the trough. 
*/
void InitVoltages(double (&T)[5][6] , double (&Tcopy)[5][6]);

/* 
Function: void CalculateVoltages(double (&T)[5][6]  , double (&Tcopy)[5][6])
arguments: References to array of the trough.
Description: 
Calculates voltages in the trough.  
*/
void CalculateVoltages(double (&T)[5][6]  , double (&Tcopy)[5][6]);

/* 
Function: void PrintVoltages(double (&T)[5][6])
arguments: Reference to array of the trough.
Description: 
Prints the trough. 
*/
void PrintVoltages(double (&T)[5][6]);


int main(void)
{
    double T[5][6] = {0};
    double Tcopy[5][6] = {0};
    std::cout << "This program prints potentials inside a trough by solving laplace equation for a\
    rectangle trough " << std::endl; 
    InitVoltages(T, Tcopy);
    CalculateVoltages(T,Tcopy);
    PrintVoltages(T);
    return 0;
}

/* 
Function: void InitVoltages(double (&T)[5][6] , double (&Tcopy)[5][6])
arguments: Reference to array of the trough.
Description: 
Initializes the trough. 
*/
void InitVoltages(double (&T)[5][6] , double (&Tcopy)[5][6])
{
   size_t index = 0;
   size_t Troughheight = 5;
   size_t Troughbreadth = 6; 
   for (index =2; index < 6 ; index ++)
   {
       Tcopy[0][index] = T[0][index]  = 100;
   }
   for (index =1; index < 5 ; index ++)
   {
       Tcopy[index][Troughbreadth-1] = T[index][Troughbreadth-1]  = 100;
   }
   Tcopy[3][4] = T[3][4]  = 100;
   for (index =1; index < Troughheight-1 ; index ++)
   {
       Tcopy[index][0] = T[index][0]  = 0;
   }
   
   Tcopy[1][1] = T[1][1]  = 0;
   for (index =1; index < Troughbreadth-2 ; index ++)
   {
       Tcopy[Troughheight-1][index] = T[Troughheight-1][index]  = 40;
   }
   Tcopy[Troughheight-1][0] = T[Troughheight-1][0]  = 20;
   Tcopy[3][3] = T[3][3]  = 70;
   Tcopy[1][2] = T[1][2]  = 50;
}

/* 
Function: void PrintVoltages(double (&T)[5][6])
arguments: pointer to array of the trough.
Description: 
Prints the trough. 
*/
void PrintVoltages(double (&T)[5][6])
{
    size_t Troughheight =5;
    size_t Troughbreadth=6;
    size_t i =0;
    size_t j =0;
    std::cout << "Voltages in the trough are: " << std::endl;
    for (i=0; i < Troughheight; i++)
    {
       for (j=0; j< Troughbreadth; j++)
        {
           if (( i ==0 && j ==0) || ( i == 0 && j==1) ||\
               ( i == 4 && j==4) || ( i == 4 && j==5)) 
           {
              std::cout << std::left << std::setw(8)<< "        "<< "   ";
           }
           else
           {
              std::cout << std::left << std::setw(8) << T[i][j] << "   ";
           }
        }
       std::cout << std::endl << std::endl << std::endl;
    }
}

/* 
Function: void CalculateVoltages(double (&T)[5][6]  , double (&Tcopy)[5][6])
arguments: References to array of the trough.
Description: 
Calculates voltages in the trough. 
*/
void CalculateVoltages(double (&T)[5][6]  , double (&Tcopy)[5][6])
{
   size_t Troughheight = 5;
   size_t Troughbreadth = 6;
   size_t index =0;
   size_t j =0;
   size_t Numofiterations = 100;
   for (size_t i =0; i <Numofiterations; i++)
   {
       /*Use previous grid values to calculate current grid values */
       T[1][3] = (Tcopy[2][3] + Tcopy[1][2] + Tcopy[0][3] + Tcopy[1][4] ) /4;
       T[1][4] = (Tcopy[2][4] + Tcopy[1][3] + Tcopy[0][4] + Tcopy[1][5] ) /4;
       T[2][1] = (Tcopy[3][1] + Tcopy[2][0] + Tcopy[1][1] + Tcopy[2][2] ) /4;
       T[2][2] = (Tcopy[3][2] + Tcopy[2][1] + Tcopy[1][2] + Tcopy[2][3] ) /4;
       T[2][3] = (Tcopy[3][3] + Tcopy[2][2] + Tcopy[1][3] + Tcopy[2][4] ) /4;
       T[2][4] = (Tcopy[3][4] + Tcopy[2][3] + Tcopy[1][4] + Tcopy[2][5] ) /4;
       T[3][1] = (Tcopy[4][1] + Tcopy[3][0] + Tcopy[2][1] + Tcopy[3][2] ) /4;
       T[3][2] = (Tcopy[4][2] + Tcopy[3][1] + Tcopy[2][2] + Tcopy[3][3] ) /4;
       /* Keep previous Voltage grid values in Tcopy */
       for (index = 0; index < Troughheight; index++)
       {  
          for (j=0; j<Troughbreadth; j++)
          {
             Tcopy[index][j]= T[index][j];
          }
       }
   }   
}

